# Function changing global variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, tetris

I have this array that I pass into a function that's suppose to rotate the array 90 deg and return the result. I then want to check whether the new array is colliding with other things on the canvas.

```
let newArray = [
[0,0,1],
[1,1,1],   
[0,0,0]
];

let test = rotate(newArray);

if ( collision(test) ){
  draw(newArray);
} else {
  draw(test);
}
```

Here's the problem. I think rotate() is changing the newArray-variable so it doesn't matter what the if-statement evaluate to, the draw() function will always do the same thing.

I want to select the array to draw after checking if the rotated matrix collides with other stuff.

```
function rotate(matrix) {

matrix = matrix.reverse();

for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
 for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
  var temp = matrix[i][j];
  matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
  matrix[j][i] = temp;
 }
}
return matrix
}


function collision(mat){

let collision = false;

for ( let i = 0; i < mat.length; i++){
for ( let j = 0; j < mat.length; j++){
  if (mat[i][j] == 1){
    let test = ctx.getImageData(x + 10*j +10, y + 10*i, 1, 1);
      if (test.data != "255,255,255,255" && test.data != "0,0,0,0"){
        collision = true;
      }
  }
 }
 }
return collision;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us rotate and collision code, please?

Comment: `I think rotate() is changing the newArray` - Where is function `rotate()` defined? Do you have the source code? If not, where is the documentation and what does that say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are correct - the `Array.reverse()` method used in the rotate function does not return a new array, it modifies the same one (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse);

I'd suggest changing the rotate function to first clone the array that's passed to it and only then perform `Array.reverse()` etc..

You can clone this simple array passed into the rotate function in your example using `let newMatrix = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix));` Then perform the remaining actions on the `newMatrix` and return that instead.

If you don't like this approach you could also create a new empty array and using a double for loop (a loop within a loop as you're working with 2D grids) populate the new array with values from the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your `rotate` function is altering your array, so it doesnt matter which `if` clause enters. Change it to this because you must clone your matrix.

```
function rotate(matrix) {

    newNatrix = matrix.slice().map( function(row){ return row.slice(); });

    for (var i = 0; i < newNatrix.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            var temp = newNatrix[i][j];
            newNatrix[i][j] = newNatrix[j][i];
            newNatrix[j][i] = temp;
        }
    }
    return newNatrix;
}
```